# How to subtract the value of one dictionary from another and write the result to the third?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am using **Python 3.8**. I get information about my elements as two dictionaries. The first dictionary retains the original information. The second dictionary is updated with the last value after a while. *I need to subtract the value of the first from the second dictionary and write the result to the third dictionary.*

```
dict1 = {'AAA': ['name1', 'link1', '100'],
         'BBB': ['name2', 'link2', '200'],
         'CCC': ['name3', 'link3', '300']
}


dict2 = {'AAA': ['name1', 'link1', '500'],
         'BBB': ['name2', 'link2', '1000'],
         'CCC': ['name3', 'link3', '1500']
}
```

**Desired output:**

```
dict3 = {'AAA': ['name1', 'link1', '400'],
         'BBB': ['name2', 'link2', '800'],
         'CCC': ['name3', 'link3', '1200']
}
```

Comment: What is that you have tried & where is it you got stuck ?

Comment: @sushanth I am stuck at this very moment, I know how to search for matches in dictionaries and write them down to the third one, but I can't figure it out with subtraction.

Comment: I posted a solution to your direct problem below, but you should look into being more efficient with how you store and access the info, it would also make it less complicated. Currently you are storing everything except the numerical values 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the position remains constant in all the values

```
dict3 = {}
for i in dict1:
    for j in dict2:
        if i == j:
            new_2 = int(dict2[j][-1])- int(dict1[i][-1])
            dict3[i] = [dict2[i][0], dict2[i][1], str(new_2)]
```

output:

```
print(dict3)

{'AAA': ['name1', 'link1', '400'],
 'BBB': ['name2', 'link2', '800'],
 'CCC': ['name3', 'link3', '1200']}
```

Comment: many answers solve my problem, but i use your solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to subtract is a value at a specific index in a list from a value at the same index in another list.

One way to do it would be:

```
from copy import deepcopy

dict3 = deepcopy(dict1) # make a copy to overwrite since most of the info is duplicated anyway

for key in dict1:
    difference_value = int(dict2[key][2]) - int(dict1[key][2])
    dict3[key][2] = str(difference_value)

print(dict3)
```

Output.

> ```
>  {'AAA': ['name1', 'link1', '400'], 'BBB': ['name2', 'link2', '800'], 'CCC': ['name3', 'link3', '1200']}
> ```

Edit: This assumes that the values you want to subtract stay it the same index in the list (2 or -1 if you want to say always the last index in the list). It also assumes that input and output are integers.

Edit2: Changed it so you are not making changes to dict1 or dict2.

Comment: This answer changes the values in dict1 which may not necessarily be desired

Comment: If you don't want the values to change, you should do dict3[key] = values.copy()

Comment: Yeah true, thanks for that. Since most of the info is copied from the other dics anyway, I changed to to be a `deepcopy` and then make changes to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to avoid nested loops then try this:

```
result = {key: dict1.get(key, 0)[:2] +
          [str(int(dict2.get(key, 0)[2]) - int(dict1.get(key, 0)[2]))]
          for key in set(dict1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses dictionary comprehension to construct a new dictionary by subtracting the keys of `dict1` from `dict2`.

```
dict3 = {
    k2: v2[:2] + [str(int(v2[-1]) - int(v1[-1]))]
    for (_, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(dict1.items(), dict2.items())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach

**Ex:**

```
dict3 = {}
for k, v in dict1.items():
    sVal = dict2.get(k)
    nval = v.copy()
    if sVal:
        nval[-1] = int(sVal[-1]) - int(nval[-1]) 
    dict3[k] = nval
    
print(dict3)
```

**Output:**

```
{'AAA': ['name1', 'link1', 400],
 'BBB': ['name2', 'link2', 800],
 'CCC': ['name3', 'link3', 1200]}
```

Comment: This answer changes the values in dict1 which may not necessarily be desired

Comment: It also does not convert the numbers back to strings, which the original question asked for (at least according to the dict 3 snipped provided)